# AB Experiment with Logistic Regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, experiment-design, clinical-trials

I have built a model and need to test the effectiveness of this. I am planning to run an AB in the following manner

1. Randomly assign population to Test Group (80%) and Control Group (20%)
2. Within Test Group, basis model threshold (say 0.6) select users for Treatment.
3. Within Control Group, no user gets treatment

For comparison of effectiveness,
all users in Test (with and without treatment) vs all users in Control (no treatment at all)

Is this procedure correct?